# layered navigation filter in magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation, pagination

Recently working on my module i need to filter product collection on the basis of certain attributes and show then on a custom page of my module i have doe this shit..

but problem is that the pagination is not working properly mean it always render the same first 6 product on all pages
another thing is that i want to add layered navigation filter on left side how to do that..

here is the repo link (on dev branch)

https://github.com/gauravnewton/Excellence_ExpressDelivery